# Remove "Description" field from taxonomy term

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a taxonomy called "Menu group" in WordPress. I'm adding my own fields to the menu group items, however the built-in field "Description" will not be used and I want to remove it. How do I go about doing that?

The following image shows the field that I want to remove:
[image: this field]

Comment: Just to be clear, this appears to just be a taxonomy that happens to be called "Menu group", right?

Comment: Yes tht is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fastest way to achieve what you want is using **CSS** otherwise JS can give you a delay and it'd display the description field anyway. Here is the solution in CSS:

```
body.taxonomy-name .term-description-wrap {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the Description field by adding the below code to your functions.php

```
function hide_description_field() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( $screen->id == 'edit-menu_group' ) {
        echo '<style>
            .term-description-wrap {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_description_field' );
```

Make sure the menu_group in line 4 is replaced with the slug of the custom taxonomy.